# Should I use the discard flag when configuring the filesystem to be installed over the partitions on my SSHD?

Tags: partition, hard-disk, ssd, trim

I've recently bought a laptop with an SSHD. My guess is that most SSHDs are [self-optimised](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_drive#Operation), so the disk itself will handle wear-levelling issues, and I won't need to add the "discard" flag when setting up my /etc/fstab for the first time.

Comment: That depends at least partly on the FS you're going to use...

Comment: ext4 in this case. :)